# Transit visa in Frankfurt

Tags: visas, schengen

I hold an Indian passport and I'm currently in the US under an F1 visa. I'm planning to go back to India, SJC - MAA. I have a 24-hour layover in Frankfurt. If I want to visit Frankfurt during that time, do I need a visa?

Comment: @fkraiem: Nonsense. One does not need a Visa when transitting in Frankfurt (from outside and out again the Schengen area). He is asking if he can leave the airport. The answer is: Just ask nicely! The probability the immigration officer will give you permission is pretty high.

Comment: @MichaelRenper You clearly have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @fkraiem. He doesn't need a Visa for just transitting. Read the regulations! The advice to "ask nicely to exit the airport" has a fair rate of succes based experiences of my Indian friends an co-workers. No guarantees.

Comment: @MichaelRenper Apologies, I overlooked the fact that OP holds a US visa. Indian nationals do ordinarily require an airport transit visa to transit in Germany, but holders of US visas are exempt.